# MPI ignores cin

Tags: c++, mpi, cin

I've write following code. It intends to read number from console (to `data` variable) and send it to all other processes. But `cin >> data` just ignored.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int rank, n;
  int i;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n);
  int data = 322; // magic number 322 just for initialisation
  if (rank == 0)
  {
    cout << "From which process do you want to transfer data?" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  else
  {
    MPI_Recv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    if (rank < n - 1)
      MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank == i) {
      cout << "Process #"<< rank <<" waiting data to send. Please enter." << endl;
      cin >> data; //doesn't work

      for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if(j != i)
          MPI_Send(&data, 1, MPI_INT, j, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {
        int pata;
        MPI_Recv(&pata, 1, MPI_INT, i, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        cout << "Process "<< rank <<" received data (" << pata << ") from process #" << i << endl;
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize( );
}
```

Console looks something like:

```
From which process do you want to transfer data?
2
Process #2 waiting data to send. Please enter.
Process 1 received data (322) from process #2
Process 3 received data (322) from process #2
```

I've already tried `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin` is generally redirected from `mpirun`/`mpiexec` to rank `0`.

There might be options (that depend on which implementation you are running) to redirect to the rank of your choice, and/or to redirect to all the ranks.

Bottom line, i do not think what you are trying is achievable.

Comment: I'm using openMPI. Thanks to your answer I've found in documentation this:

`-stdin, --stdin <rank>
The MPI_COMM_WORLD rank of the process that is to receive stdin. The default is to forward stdin to MPI_COMM_WORLD rank 0, but this option can be used to forward stdin to any process. It is also acceptable to specify none, indicating that no processes are to receive stdin.`

Unfortunately, I see no option to redirect to all the ranks. I think that this will do just what I want.

Anyway, now I know what happening. Thank You.